# ngRoute- direct url not displaying template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ngroute

I'm newer to angular so I'm sorry if this is really obvious! I'm making a super basic app and right now all I want is when a user directly goes to a page it should always display the layout and the content. I am using angular's `ng-route`.

As of right now, if I go to localhost:8080/ it displays the layout(index.html) and content(view/home.html). If I click on the 'About' link, it goes to localhost:8080/about and displays the layout(index.html) and the correct content(view/about.html). Now if I type localhost:8080/about in my address bar, hit enter, I get a 404 error from my server's log. I'm not sure what I'm missing. Any input appreciated!

app.js

```
  angular
  .module('TestProject', ['ngRoute']);
```

routes.js

```
angular.module('TestProject')
  .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'views/home.html'
      })
      .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html'
      })
      .when('/contact', {
        templateUrl: 'views/contact.html'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/"
      });

      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  });
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="TestProject">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test!</title>

    <base href="/">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/app.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header><h1>Logo</h1></header>
    <nav>
      <ul class="main">
        <li>
          <div class="navBorder">
            <a href="about">About</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="navBorder">
            <a href="contact">Contact</a>
          </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

    <div ng-view></div>

    <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="routes.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I know I don't have any controllers yet, I just started this project and there's nothing there yet.

Here are how my files are organized:

My file structure is below:

```
/index.html
/app.js
/routes.js

/views/home.html
/views/about.html
/views/contact.html
```

Comment: Where is index.html coming from?

Comment: index.html is in the main directory, I'll update my question with the directories of where my files are

Comment: What backend technology are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If using AngularJS 1.3+, you need to include a notion of a `<base href="" />`. You can do this in your `<head>` tag as such

```
<head>
    <base href="/">
...
```

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase)

> Before Angular 1.3 we didn't have this hard requirement and it was
>   easy to write apps that worked when deployed in the root context but
>   were broken when moved to a sub-context because in the sub-context all
>   absolute urls would resolve to the root context of the app. To prevent
>   this, use relative URLs throughout your app:

Additionally, without this `<base />` tag, you can declare `.html5Mode()` as such... You'll need to take one of these two approaches.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
});
```

Comment: I've got this in my index.html file already. I'll update my question to also include the source.

Answer (score 1):

Ahhh I figured it out, it was a problem with my server. I had not set up `mod_rewrite` for it to work properly. For the time being I turned off `html5Mode()` and everything works fine.